# I got 1064 error when running prepare statement with if condition

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_proc`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `test_proc`(param_a int)
BEGIN
set @sqlstr_3=concat('if (1=',param_a,') then ');
set @sqlstr_3=concat(@sqlstr_3, 'select 1;else select 2;');
set @sqlstr_3=concat(@sqlstr_3, ' end if;');
select @sqlstr_3;
/**
prepare stmt_3 from @sqlstr_3;
execute stmt_3;
deallocate prepare stmt_3;
*/
if (1=param_a) then select 1;else select 2; end if;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call this procedure using:**call test_proc(2)** ,it works fine and returns two result:
result1: if (1=2) then select 1;else select 2; end if;
result2: 2

But when I using prepare statement.It got errors.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test_proc`;
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `test_proc`(param_a int)
BEGIN
set @sqlstr_3=concat('if (1=',param_a,') then ');
set @sqlstr_3=concat(@sqlstr_3, 'select 1;else select 2;');
set @sqlstr_3=concat(@sqlstr_3, ' end if;');
select @sqlstr_3;

prepare stmt_3 from @sqlstr_3;
execute stmt_3;
deallocate prepare stmt_3;

-- if (1=param_a) then select 1;else select 2; end if;
END
;;
DELIMITER ;
```

I call this procedure using:**call test_proc(2)** ,it got some errors:

[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (1=2) then select 1;else select 2; end if' at line 1

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Prepare statement may prepare single statement only, not compound statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to use dynamic SQL for compound statement then you must convert it into single statement. For example, your

```
if (1=param_a) then select 1;else select 2; end if;
```

may be converted to something near

```
select 1 WHERE (1=param_a)
UNION ALL
select 2 WHERE NOT (1=param_a);
```

---

Alternatively you may use separate conditional blocks with individual SQL statement creation (and maybe even PREPAREs):

```
IF 1=param_a THEN
    set @sqlstr_3='select 1;';
ELSE
    set @sqlstr_3='select 2;';
END IF;

PREPARE stmt_3 FROM @sqlstr_3;
EXECUTE stmt_3;
DROP PREPARE stmt_3;
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.Now I've transform 【if exists (xxx) then】 style to:【select exists (xxx) into @res_exists】 and then prepare it.